# Sum a colum per x and per y in a Datafame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, sum

I have:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "ID": [55218,55218,55218,55218,55222], 
  "Product": [10,10,22,22,21],
  "Cluster": [0,0,1,2,1]  
  "Rating":[-1,2,0,1,2]})
```

I want to sum every 0, 1 or 2 in "Cluster" for every x in "ID" and every y in "Product"

My expected output is:

```py
df_new = pd.DataFrame({"ID": [55218,55218,55218,55222], 
  "Product": [10,22,22,21],
  "Cluster": [0,1,2,1], 
  "Sum": [[1,0,1,2] })
```

Comment: Is it necessary to keep values inside [ ]? can you get rid of them? or they are part of the problem?

Comment: Yes i can get rid of them. I'll change my question

Answer (score 1):

This will gives you desired output

```
import pandas as pd
# Query DF
df = pd.DataFrame({
  "ID": [[55218],[55218],[55218],[55218],[55222]], 
  "Product": [[10],[10],[22],[22],[21]],
  "Cluster": [[0],[0],[1],[2],[1]],  
  "Rating":[[-1],[2],[0],[1],[2]]})
print(df)

unique_list =[]
sum = []
for i in range(df.shape[0]):
  entry =[[df.loc[i]['ID'][0]],[df.loc[i]['Product'][0]],[df.loc[i]['Cluster'][0]]]
  if entry not in unique_list:
    unique_list.append(entry)
    sum.append([df.loc[i]['Rating'][0]])
  else:
    ind = unique_list.index(entry)
    sum[ind] = [sum[ind][0] + df.loc[i]['Rating'][0]]

# Required DF
df_new = pd.DataFrame(unique_list)
df_new['Sum'] = sum
df_new.columns = ['ID' ,'Product', 'Cluster', 'Sum']
print(df_new)
```

Input

```
        ID Product Cluster Rating
0  [55218]    [10]     [0]   [-1]
1  [55218]    [10]     [0]    [2]
2  [55218]    [22]     [1]    [0]
3  [55218]    [22]     [2]    [1]
4  [55222]    [21]     [1]    [2]
```

Output

```
        ID Product Cluster Sum
0  [55218]    [10]     [0]    [1]
1  [55218]    [22]     [1]    [0]
2  [55218]    [22]     [2]    [1]
3  [55222]    [21]     [1]    [2]
```

Comment: @Mars, Was this answer helpful? If so, then please upvote this answer.

Comment: Yes it works, but very very slowly. Is there a better solution?

Comment: Sorry, Not in my knowledge.